# If I enable bandwidth control on my wifi router can I handle more connections reliably?

Tags: router, wifi, bandwidth

I have a small router (TP-Link TL-WR841N) bandwidth is 300 Mbps. With default settings it cannot handle more than 10 connections without choking and kicking people out.
Theoretically, however, it can accept 253 simultaneous connections (number of assignable addresses).

I am using it in a setup where the **bandwidth per user is not so important, on the other hand the reliability of the connection is critical** (people shouldn't get disconnected).

I was therefore wondering if by limiting the bandwidth per user in my router's settings I could ensure a greater reliability and maybe cope with about 50 simultaneous (and reliable) connections? Or is the reliability also depending on other factors?

Comment: I hate to say but this likely is not a router issue per se but your signal quality is crappy. Unless you put that thing into the middle of an empty room you likely have a signal strengh issue and to mitigate this you start putting up repeaters and / or access points. The range of 300Mbit WIFI through sthings like walls is not exactly stellar.

Comment: Actually we are using it in an empty room, and there's no walls :) so I think the signal quality is rather good ...

Comment: If you can not get things working check out Mikrotik requipment - dead cheap.... though sadly no dual band without some home-working (they can do it, sell the boards, just not nicely packaged up into a box).